# Solving 2nd order partial differential equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve given partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=a\frac{\partial (xp)}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

**Here is my attempt:**

We have that
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=a\frac{\partial (xp)}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$
Rewriting the equation as
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}-a(p\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})=b\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$
Applying the product rule of derivates
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}-a(p\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})=b\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$
Hence
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}-a(p(1)+x\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})=b\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}-ap-ax\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=b\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$
where
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=0$$
$$\frac{-a}{b}(p+x\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})=\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}$$
Which yields
$$\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}=\frac{-a}{b}(p+x\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})$$

Comment: Are there any boundary/initial conditions?

Comment: @rafa11111 No, there aren't.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: It's very unlikely that you have a PDE without boundary conditions. In which circumstances did you find this equation? Is it a math problem?

Comment: @rafa11111 Yes, it is. However, I don't actually know what will be changed once I have a PDE without boundary conditions. What about assuming that $a = 0$?

Comment: @rafa11111 Does the equation seem uncomplete or wrong to you?

Comment: Are you the same user from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835272/how-to-solve-this-2nd-order-partial-differential-equation)?

Comment: Also, are you just trying to find the steady-state solution, since you set $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=0$? This problem feels incomplete, where did it come from?.

Comment: @Dylan No, I'm not.

Comment: @Dylan Indeed, I demanded to solve it. However, I couldn't make sure whether my assumtion is correct. Does there exist anything unclear on the question? perhaps it is truly unclear.

Comment: I also have been told that for solution to this equation $T = c_1e^{\lambda t}$ needs to be found. Is that right?

Comment: @Hamilton Unlike ODE's, the behavior of PDE's can change drastically with the boundary conditions. AFAIK, you can find two "classes" of solutions to your equation. Since it's a parabolic equation, you can solve it by separation of variables, assuming that $p(x,t) = T(t)\cdot X(x)$, obtaining therefore two ODE's (one from $T$ and one for $X$) or through the introduction of a similarity variable $\eta=f(x,t)$ such that $p = g(\eta)$. It seems that you should try the former method, due to the information that you must find $T=c_1e^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: @rafa11111 Honestly, do you expect this question can be solved? In other words, I've taken different answers from my professors. One of them used seperation of values, and the other one used this method as seen on my question. Are both way correct in spades? I'll be waiting for a reply.

Comment: If you must get something like $T=c_1 e^{\lambda t}$, I'm sure that you need to use separation of variables. If you assume that ${\partial p}/{\partial t}=0$, you get an ODE whose solution is quite simple. However, there is no sense in doing this assumption in this context.

Comment: @rafa11111 It's not depending on $T = c_1e^{\lambda t}$, my other professor had mentioned that, which consequently forced me to share it with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeking a solution by separation of variables, we have $p = X(x)T(t)$. Substituting in the equation,
$$
X\dot{T} = a\left( XT + xX'T \right) + b X''T,
$$
being $X' = dX/dx$ and $\dot{T} = dT/dt$. Dividing by $XT$:
$$
\frac{\dot{T}}{T} = a\left( 1 + x\frac{X'}{X} \right) + b \frac{X''}{X}.
$$
See that the LHS is a function only of $t$ and the RHS is a function only of $x$. It is only possible if $x=t$, which is nonsense, or if they are both equal to a constant value, say, $\lambda$. Then:
$$
\frac{\dot{T}}{T} = a\left( 1 + x\frac{X'}{X} \right) + b \frac{X''}{X} = \lambda,
$$
or,
$$
\dot{T} - \lambda T = 0,
$$
$$
b X'' + a x X' + (a-\lambda)X = 0.
$$
Now, we have two ODE's instead of one PDE. It's a great advance! Solving the equation for $T$:
$$
T = c_1 \exp \lambda T.
$$
See that we will want that $\lambda<0$, because, in that case, our solution will not explode to $\infty$ for large $t$. The equation for $X$ can be transformed into the [Hermite equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html), and you can solve it through power series or use the fancy solution given by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b*X%27%27(x)+%2B+ax*X%27(x)+%2B+(a-lambda)*X(x)%3D0). Anyway, it will have the form
$$
X = c_2 F_1(x;\lambda) + c_3 F_2(x;\lambda),
$$
in which $F_1$ and $F_2$ are crazy functions (that you will probably never see again) and the solution will be
$$
p(x,t;\lambda) = e^{\lambda t} (A F_1(x;\lambda) + B F_2(x;\lambda)).
$$

See that the solution depends somehow of $\lambda$, which is not an input of the problem! That's because we have an eigenvalue problem, that only can be completed with the boundary conditions and the initial conditions. With the boundary conditions we will discover the values of $\lambda$ for which our solution works. There will be, probably, infinite possible values for $\lambda$, and we will need to sum $p(x,t;\lambda)$ for every possible $\lambda$, leading to a Fourier-like series. Also, the initial condition will show us which values $A$ and $B$ must assume. Therefore, the solution will be complete, with the form
$$
p(x,t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{\lambda_k t} (A_k F_1(x;\lambda_k) + B_k F_2(x;\lambda_k)).
$$

That's why the problem statement is incomplete without the boundary and initial conditions. We solved only half of the problem, and we only know that our expression $p(x,t;\lambda)$ satisfies the original PDE. However, unlike ODE's, we can conclude nothing of the final solution (without boundary conditions) with what we got. See, for example, this simpler equation:
$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2},
$$
known as the heat equation. If we follow the same steps, we will get
$$
p(x,t;\lambda) = e^{\lambda t} (A \sin \lambda x + B \cos \lambda x).
$$
You may think "perhaps the final solution, after applying the boundary and initial conditions, will be oscilatory!". However, if we apply the conditions
$$
p(x,0) = 0; \ \ \ p(0,t) = 0; \ \ \ p(L,t) = 1
$$
we will get a monotonic equation, without any kind of peak or oscilation.